# Downloading image from Firebase (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download an image from Firebase Storage and display it in my app. The way I'm trying to get a download url is as follows:

```
let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/' + 'userImage');
    imageRef
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then((url) => {
    console.log(url)
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log('getting downloadURL of image error => ', e));
```

Now, this logs out the url perfectly. However it is inaccessible from outside this function. If I try to acces it even right after the .catch I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: url

This means of course that I can't call the url when I'm trying to display the image in the following way:

```
<Image source={{uri: url}} />
```

Any ideas on how to approach this issue and solve it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to store the URL in the state of the component, instead of in a variable:

```
let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/' + 'userImage');
    imageRef
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then((url) => {
      setState({ url: url });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log('getting downloadURL of image error => ', e));
```

That will not only ensure that the render method can find it, but also that the output is re-rendered once the URL has been calculated.

---

If you [use hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), you'd have something like:

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState();

let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/' + 'userImage');
    imageRef
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then((url) => {
      setUrl(url);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log('getting downloadURL of image error => ', e));
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks a lot for your answer and your kind explanation.

Comment: I would just add that to set the URL in the image tag, it should be: <img src={url} />